# I am trying to find effective solution for my Homework. Bubble Sort or Insertion Sort?

Tags: algorithm, sorting

Hello everyone i have a question. It's my task which one is below:

Let A[] be a natural numbers array of length N, which is partially sorted, i.e. there exists such index i(0 < i < N-1), that the subaray A[0],...,A[i] is incrementally sorted and also the subarray A[i+1],...,A[N] is incrementally sorted. Design the algorithm, which sorts the whole array A[] and works in place (so has space complexity O(1)) and the result must be stored in the same array A[]. Describe the algorithm, its correctness and its time complexity approximation.

For this question which approaching is better? Bubble sorting or Insertion sort? Or is there more effective solution? I prefered bubble sorting for this task but i am open to other opinions

```
static void bubbleSort(int arr[], int n) 
{ 
    int i, j, temp; 
    boolean swapped; 
    for (i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)  
    { 
        swapped = false; 
        for (j = 0; j < n - i - 1; j++)
        { 
            if (arr[j] > arr[j + 1])  
            { 
                // swap arr[j] and arr[j+1] 
                temp = arr[j]; 
                arr[j] = arr[j + 1]; 
                arr[j + 1] = temp; 
                swapped = true; 
            } 
        } 


        if (swapped == false) 
            break; 
    } 
} 

static void printArray(int arr[], int size) 
{ 
    int i; 
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) 
        System.out.print(arr[i] + " "); 
    System.out.println(); 
}


 public static void main(String args[]) 
{ 
    int arr[] = { 1, 8, 45, 12, 22, 11, 90 }; 
    int n = arr.length; 
    bubbleSort(arr, n); 
    System.out.println("Sorted array: "); 
    printArray(arr, n); 
}
```

}

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Since this sounds like a homework question, I'd suggest trying with sample data and debug the code, either with a debugger or using print statements in the code and see the order of the execution, as well as the number of operations performed. Asking for an answer here won't (effectively) help you. Please also read [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/10400050)

Comment: Thank you for answer. Yes you have right its a homework question but point is i am trying to understand exactly. I am not asking just for answer. I choose bubble sort because array is already partially sorted and i have to sort all array then bubble sort will give a minimum sorting time. Insertion sort will take maximum time because of that bubble sorting seems like a better

Comment: Okay you could have right but lets assume "Let A[] be a natural numbers array of length N" then which algorithm you will prefer and why? I couldnt understand this part. Edit : After small search i understood what you mean exactly but still i have question if we will have more elements then Bubble sort won't be more usefull?

Comment: both algorithm will have worst case : O(n2) and best case : o(n) also space complexities are the same : O(1)

Comment: *"Let A[] be a natural numbers array of length N"* only says that A is an array of N numbers. It says nothing about the order or their nature, other that they are natural numbers (basically non-negative and not floats/decimals). `A` could therefore be `[1]` or `[0, 0, 0]` or `[1, 10, 100, 1000]` or `[5, 4, 3]` or anything with any length.

Comment: @Johan okay i understood that already i just meant number of element i could be more and more. Let's say 100 element of an array some of them partially sorted. By the way i hope i am not disturbing or making you angry with my questions

Comment: @RamazanAçıkgöz If I would get angry I would just refrain from answering :) Don't worry about it, I'm just trying to help you make your question clearer so people understand it easier.

Comment: @Johan Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bubble sort algorithm complexity is O(n^2). Even using `if (swapped == false) break;` this will not help to reduce the complexity (try for {2,3,4,5,1}, you will find out).

Since there exists such index `i(0 < i < N-1)`, that the subaray `A[0],...,A[i]` is incrementally sorted and also the subarray `A[i+1],...,A[N]` is incrementally sorted.This problem can be solve in O(n) run time complexity. If we can find the index `i` where `A[0:i] and A[i+1:n] are sorted`, then we can think this problem as merging two sorted array into one array which can be done in O(n) time. Algorithm is given below:

```
void sortPartialSortedArray(int arr[], int n) 
{
    int pos = 0; 
    // find the position for which arr[0:pos] and arr[pos+1:n] is sorted
    for(int i=0; i+1<n; i++) {
        if(arr[i]>arr[i+1]) {
            pos = i; 
        }
    }

    int i = pos, j= n-1;

    // sort it from last position
    while(i>=0 && j>=0) {
        if(arr[i] > arr[j]) {
            swap(arr[i],arr[j]);
        }
        j--;
        if(i==j) {
            i--;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Really nice solution right now i understood what you mean. After finding position which is sorted and start to sort from there and after that two sorted array into one array cool! I didnt think from this perspective. I just focused to sort an array and min complexity will be O(n2) and it will be enough. But really thanks for all explanation you opened my mind.

Comment: Glad i can help.. @RamazanAçıkgöz the way to say thanks in stackoverflow is by giving upvote.